# Filter / image texture Iphone

Tags: iphone, camera

Good!
I need to add the image of the iPhone's camera filter / texture through a UIImagePickerController, but do not know how to directly access the camera image, since only with access to the eye.

The filter may be black / white, sepia or anything else.

Thank you very much! regards

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed the problem by adding a mask to the image, so it was not necessary to apply a filter lol.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look here [Apple Reference on Image Picker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to see what you would need to select an image taken from the camera.

You can then apply the filters you need to this image any way you want.

Apple provides a nice sample project to do this: [PhotoPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) You may want to try this out too.

If you need to have an effect that's added on the preview layer in real-time, you'll need to go into a bit lower api's methods, like the AVCaptureSessions and OpenGLES2.0 shaders. There is a good introduction into real-time shader's for the iPhone 4 at: [Introduction to Augmented Reality on the iPhone by Nick Waynik](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone). This should help you in figuring out how to add real-time augmentation to the preview layer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to add an effect directly to UIImagePickerController or however real-time on the photo preview.
Any ideas?